# What wood can I use to make a jewelry box with a scroll saw?

Tags: wood-selection

I’m fairly new to wood working. I took a shop class in school years ago but that’s about the extent of my knowledge. I was wondering what a good wood would be to make a jewelry box using the scroll saw? Also does it matter what blades you use?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to SE. While this is a perfectly good Question I think you'd be better off asking it on a dedicated forum for a couple of reasons. You could get a researched Answer here but you'd be better served getting a wider range of responses from people actively involved in scroll-saw work, and you'd have the opportunity to ask any follow-on questions that might arise. And it wouldn't hurt to embed yourself in such a community anyway for all the usual benefits the conventional forum model allows (something almost completely lacking here because of the way the site works).

Comment: Hello Mike, welcome to the Woodworking Stack Exchange! Graphus provided some great tips for getting more in-depth answers from a more focused scroll saw community.  I see a couple potential questions here. To make this question a better fit for this site, you could post a separate question for each part; for example, one question about what types of wood are suitable for intricate scroll saw work, and a separate question about when to use different types of blades.